# How can I configure Visual Studio 2008 Express Edition to c89/c90/c99?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008

I'm getting lots of compiler errors due to standards' issues.

Comment: Changed tag from "C++" to C as the title refer to ISO C releases.

Comment: VS is C++, the 'C support' is just an added feature/bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know Visual C++ does not have options to conform to particular standards. Rather it's on a sort of fuzzy, sliding scale, each version introducing some more support for current and future standards.

Last year, [Microsoft wrote](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/485416/support-c99) "Currently, there are no plans to implement C99 support in VS2010."

However, the C++ tag you've placed on your question is perhaps not totally irrelevant: C++ provides most of the functionality that you have in C99, plus much more. Not stack based variable length arrays, though. But it's not something you'd miss.

Comment: The biggest thing (IMO) from C99 that Visual C++ does not (yet) support is the C99 standard library additions.  Thankfully, these are incorporated into C++0x so they'll (eventually) be supported by Visual C++ (one would think, at least).